# React Native: Custom component w/ a function in a prop - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a custom component that wraps native `<Text>` component for a [Limited Style Inheritance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#limited-style-inheritance) . In my custom component I have a `function` in the `style` `prop` to dynamically evaluate a custom `font` `prop` and decide what font to render.

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

const evaluateFont = (font = 'regular') => {
  console.log('[evaluateFont]');
  switch (font) {
    case 'regular':
      return styles.fontRegular;
    case 'semibold':
      return styles.fontSemibold;
    case 'bold':
      return styles.fontBold;
  }
};

const MyText = (props) => {
  const { children, style, font, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <MyText>
      <Text
        style={[evaluateFont(font), style]}
        {...rest}
      >
        {children}
      </Text>
    </MyText>
  );
};

export default MyText;
```

But when running my app I get the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` Error.
Why my `evaluateFont()` `fn` cause this & keeps running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not your `evaluateFont()`, it's the `<MyText></MyText>` in your return statement that's creating a that's causing the stack issue. Try removing the extraneous `<MyText></MyText>` and see if that works any better.

Comment: Oh! I've made such a foolish mistake... Thanks for pointing on this! Now it works!